# How to update ngModel when updating ui-ace editor's value using setValue?

Tags: angularjs, ace-editor, ui-ace

I'm using ui-ace directive to implement ace editor in an angular application.
I have a button that I use to dynamically add data to an ace editor.
Now when a user clicks on the button, I use setValue method to update the value of ace editor but the value doesn't reflect in ngModel. What is the best way to do so?

Here's how I set the value...

```
$scope.addUserInput = function (input) {
    var currentValue = $scope.aceEditor.getValue();

    if(SqlTokenizer.isIdentifier(input.name)){
        $scope.aceEditor.setValue(currentValue + ":" + input.name, false);
    } else{
        $scope.aceEditor.setValue(currentValue + ':"'+ input.name +'"', false);
    }
};
```

I've created plunkr for the same here http://plnkr.co/edit/ez0cwr6PWhALpqu3wjZT?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

updated plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/GCnDPQnC7xoC6xqdOeqd

The problem is ur adding/updating the text in your editor dont need to do that.

just need to update your scope variable it will reflect in all the bind places.

instead of this

```
//$scope.editor.setValue($scope.editor.getValue() + new Date().getTime());
```

Do this

```
$scope.text = $scope.text + new Date().getTime();
```